# C Program to Remove all Characters in a String Except Alphabets (the program display weird things)

Tags: c

so I wrote this simple program, to remove all Characters in a String Except Alphabets. 
what I did was I made an array with ascii characters ( I know its not complete ), and then loop to check if the given array contains one of the ascii character in the ascii array if so then replace it with space, then we left with an array with just alphabet and spaces. then a for loop check the number of the alphabet character in the array and that would be the length of the new array (t starts with 1 so it could be place for the null terminator ) and last is the while loop where fill the new arrays with the alphabet characters and then puts() function to display it .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int i=0,j=0,t=1;
  char a[30];
  char b[t];
  char ascii[21] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',
  '9',' ', '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')'};


  printf("enter your line:");
  fgets(a, 30, stdin);

  for(i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    for(j=0;ascii[j]!= '\0';j++)
    {
      if (a[i] == ascii [j] ) {
        a[i] = ' ';
      } 
      else continue;
    }
  }

 for(i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (a[i] != ' ') t++; 
  }

while (a[i] != '\0' & b[i] != '\0')
{
  if (a[i] != ' ') {
    a[i] = b[j];
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}

puts(b);

}
```

the compiler shows this

```
enter your line:caris$mo89
�2j.�
```

i assume its garbage values and I don't really know where the problem exactly.

Comment: You never assign anything to `b`.  And `b` is only one element long, since `t` is `1`.  What did you expect to see in `b`?

Comment: None of your strings are NUL-terminated. This can lead to possible undefined behavior.

Comment: Just use `isalpha()` instead. But that's not the only problem: `char b[t];` holds one character even though you increment `t` later (and remember to terminate the string before passing it to `puts`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in less code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char a[30];
  int i = 0;

  printf("enter your line:");
  fgets(a, 30, stdin);

  while(a[i] != '\0') {
    //check if it's not an alphabet char uppercase and lowercase of course
    if(!(a[i] >= 65 && a[i] <= 90 || a[i] >= 97 && a[i] <= 122)) {
      a[i] = ' ';
    }
    i++;
  }

  printf("%s", a);
}
```